# как проверить подтип конструктора?

Tags: typescript

Eсть следующие классы

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}

class D extends A {}
```

Имеется конструктор класса A:

```
let atype: new() => A;

atype = D;
```

Можно ли определить: имеет ли объект, создаваемый данным конструктором, тип, который является подтипом класса B?
Не создавая при этом экземпляр atype:  `new atype() instanceof B`

Comment: Тут случаем не подразумевается `class D extends C {}`?

Comment: Нет, тогда бы не было смысла в такой проверке

Comment: т.е. проверка после `atype = C;` должна давать положительный результат, а после `atype = D;` - отрицательный?

Comment: `atype = D` это не проверка, это присвоение. Если после этого сделать  `new atype() instanceof B;` то результат будет `false`. А если так `atype = C; new atype() instanceof B` будет `true`. Я искал способ избавится от создания объекта. Сейчас думаю, что такого способа нету, поэтому реализовал так.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого будет достаточно пробежаться по прототипам функции-конструктора:

```
import {strictEqual as Assert_Eq} from 'assert';

/**
@param base - Функция-конструктор, наличие которой в цепочке прототипов
    требуется определить.
@param derived - Функция-конструктор, цепочку прототипов которой надо проверить.
    При рекурсивном вызове в этом параметре будет передаваться либо
    функция-конструктор базового класса, либо некоторый объект или null
    (при отсутствии наследования).
**/
function Check_Inheritance(base: Function, derived?: Function | any): boolean
{
    let result = false;
    if("function" === typeof derived)
    {
        if(base === derived)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = Check_Inheritance(base, Object.getPrototypeOf(derived));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
class D extends A {}

let atype: new () => A;
atype = D;
Assert_Eq(false, Check_Inheritance(B, atype));
atype = C;
Assert_Eq(true, Check_Inheritance(B, atype));
process.exit(0);
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. Оно натолкнуло меня на такую проверку: `base === derived || base.isPrototypeOf(derived);`

Answer (score 1):

Реализация стандартными средствами языка через **isPrototypeOf**:

```
function checkInheritance(base: Function, derived: Function): boolean {
    return (base === derived || base.isPrototypeOf(derived));
}

class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
class D extends A {}

let atype: new () => A;

atype = A;
console.log(checkInheritance(B, atype)); //false

atype = B;
console.log(checkInheritance(B, atype)); //true

atype = C;
console.log(checkInheritance(B, atype)); //true

atype = D;
console.log(checkInheritance(B, atype)); //false
```

Есть еще один пример через **instanceof**, работает аналогично:

```
//A === B || A.prototype instanceof B

function checkInheritance(base: Function, derived: Function): boolean {
    return (base === derived || derived.prototype instanceof base);
}
```

Базовая имплементация *instanceof*:

```
function instanceof(obj, Constr) {
    var proto;
    while ((proto = Object.getProtoypeOf(obj)) {
        if (proto === Constr.prototype) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```